# typescript cannot find module when import svg file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack, webpack-file-loader

It's web application created with Typescript, React and webpack. I want to use svg file through webpack. However, I got

```
    TS2307: Cannot find module '~/images/slide.svg'.
```

Typescript files are put on /frontend/src/, and typescript files are build successfully.

Then, I tried some solutions on website. But I could not solve this problem.
What I tried is described briefly as follows.

I added a file where defined types in 'typeRoots'.
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./app/assets/javascripts/bundles",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "removeComments": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./frontend/src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["types", "node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useCache": true,
    "cacheDirectory": "tmp/build_caches/awesome-typescript-loader"
  },
  "include": [
    "./frontend/src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bundles",
    "**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

types/images.d.ts

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

I use 'file-loader' on webpack to build svg fild.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is because of your *include* section in the Typescript config.
Try this:

```
"include": [
  "./frontend/src/**/*"
],
```

Otherwise you are only including typing files which are in *src* folder top level. And your *svg* typing file is in a sublevel so Typescript will not include it.

Comment: File specification cannot end in a recursive directory wildcard ('**'): './src/*/**'.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using `Nextjs`, you can create a new file `additional.d.ts` (same  level as `next-env.d.ts`) and declare modules for image files. You should then include this file in your `tsconfig.json`.

`additional.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.gif";
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "additional.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. including "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx" after my "src/custom.d.ts"

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer caused odd behavior for me. For example, my build was not failing if I referenced an undefined variable.

What worked for me:

1. Create `custom.d.ts` in project root:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

2. Add `custom.d.ts` in tsconfig.json's include

```
"include": [
  ...,
  "custom.d.ts"
]
```

3. Usage:

```
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from '../icon.svg'

...

function MyComponent() {
  return <MyIcon></MyIcon>
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the current one didn't worked for me.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal I couldn't agree more!

Comment: Better to put in  `/{project_root}/types/svg.module.d.ts`

Comment: https://duncanleung.com/typescript-module-declearation-svg-img-assets/
This seems to have some good info too

Answer (score 3):

I'd be better included like this:

```
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "images.d.ts"],
```

Comment: Why it would be better?